# PostgreSQL: extract each line of a query result to s separate file

Tags: postgresql

If I have a query like:

```
SELECT key1, key2, text FROM mytable WHERE...
```

And I want to save the results out such that each result ends up in its own file, and the file is named based on the values of key1 and key2 (plus a timestamp to ensure unique file names).

Example -- if this is the result of my query:

```
key1    | key2    | text
12345   | A       | a bunch of text
23513   | Q       | a bunch more text
```

I want to end up with two files, one named something like `12345_D_139050886127` containing `a bunch of text` and another named something like `23513_Q_139050886131` containing `a bunch more text`.

My question is: are there postgresql tools that would do this easily, or should I just export the result of the query to a CSV file, and then write a perl script or whatever to break it into multiple small files.  The disadvantage of the latter method would be at least temporarily requiring double the disk storage space -- the query replies may be quite large (but this shouldn't be a huge problem).

Comment: SQL Workbench/J can do that using its WbExport command: http://sql-workbench.net/manual/command-export.html#export-example-lobs

Comment: You can use `psql` to pipe the results directly to the perl script. This way it will be faster and wont require additional space.

Comment: That sounds like the simplest approach @IgorRomanchenko. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to write a simple Java program, it could do easily the job. Moreover, if errors occur, you will see quickly if the error concerns the DB access, file writing or anything else. Finally, improve or update your program will be a piece of cake ;)

Comment: I write Java all the time, but is there an API for accessing a PostgreSQL server from Java?

Comment: There are many useful frameworks such as Hibernate but for your needs, a basic JDBC access will be sufficient. Use org.postgresql.Driver as driver class and a URL which looks like jdbc:postgresql://${DB_SERVER}:${SQL_LISTEN_PORT}/${DB_NAME}

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PL/Perl, PL/Python, or whatever, so long as the location you want to write to is one that the PostgreSQL server has permission to access.

That said, there's no need. You can consume rows into your script a few at a time by reading from a cursor, or just by using [`fetchrow_arrayref`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=273952) to progressively read data from the server.